# PHP jquery set checkbox value if checked or unchecked and post

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I want to set value for the check when it is unchecked. But every time I post my data whatever it is checked or unchecked, the value will be '1'

I tried to set `!isset($check)` in `post.php`, but the value also will be 1.

How can I set the different value when I uncheck the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1">
```

The jquery code is below:

```
var check = $('#check').val();
var Data = {check:check};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"post.php",
    data:Data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#btn-submit").html('sending');
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: `:checked` selector. `prop('checked')` or other ways. Internet is full of tutorials.

Comment: `$('#check').val();` change to `$('#check').is(":checked");` will send true or false depending on state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `val()` of the checkbox is always the same regardless of whether the element is checked or not.

To do what you require you can set the value based on the `checked` state. Try this:

```
var $check = $('#check');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "post.php",
  data: { 
    check: $check.prop('checked') ? $check.val() : 0 
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#btn-submit").html('sending');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // do something with the response
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `is(':checked')` to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not:

```js
$("#check").on('change', function() {
  var checkFlag = 'unchecked';
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkFlag = 'checked';
  }

  console.log(checkFlag);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: {
      check: checkFlag
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#btn-submit").html('sending');
    },
    success: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="1">
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps the OP send the value in his AJAX request?

Comment: Well, it gets you to know whether its checked or not and he just needs to send that as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`var check = $('#check').is(":checked");`

**When checkbox is checked**

You will get `true`

**When checkbox is not checked**

You will get `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#check").is(':checked')) {
   var check = $('#check').val();
}else{
   var check = 0;
}
var Data = {check:check};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"post.php",
    data:Data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#btn-submit").html('sending');
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```